# How many boxes so that there is $k$ of same of color from $n$ different colors?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, asymptotics, measure-concentration

Say you have $m$ boxes each of which is colored with one of $n$ colors. What should $m$ be so that the probability that there is atleast $k$ boxes with one same color is strictly greater than $\frac{1}{2}$?

If $k = \Theta(n^{c})$, then what is $m$ if $c < 1$, $c > 1$? Is $m = \Omega(n^{c+1})$ in general?

I was trying to generalize birthday paradox problem. By Pigeon hole I can get only $m=\Omega(n^{2})$ if $k=O(n)$ for 'certainty'. Using pigeon hole I cannot give a probabilistic argument here. Was curious for general sizes of $m$, $n$ and $k$ and what would replace pigeon hole?

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~tkemp/180A/180A.LectureNotes.pdf says answer for $n=365$ and general $k$ was not known till $1995$ but does not provide reference.

In this problem, there are two cases: $k < n$ and $k > n$.

Comment: If $k=\Theta(n)$ then you should need $m=\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: You can rule out any power smaller than quadratic by Hoeffding's inequality, which isn't sharp.

Comment: Can you explain more? I also think n^2 is needed but Ben's answer which uses Talagrand's inequality seems to imply quasilinearness!

Comment: I could say more, but this is not research level mathematics. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality The application is straightforward. If you want to know more about what Ben Barber meant, ask him.

Comment: Sorry Arul, I was imagining $k$ fixed, which is not the question you asked.  If $k = \Theta (n)$ then my heuristic agrees with what Douglas Zare said.

Comment: You accepted an incorrect answer? Ok, I'm done with this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Doughlas: I think I got what I wanted and I understood what you said. It is pretty clear. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

Googling on "birthday problem 1995" turns up references to a paper by L. Holst, the [abstract](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/rsa.3240060207/abstract) to which reads

> The general birthday problem with unlike birth probabilities and the
>   waiting time N until c people with the same birthday have been
>   obtained is studied in this article. It is shown that N is
>   stochastically largest when the birth probabilities are equal. By
>   embedding in Poisson processes it is shown how the moments of N can be
>   expressed in moments of the minimum of gamma random variables.

The Holst paper doesn't appear to be available online, but a later paper by [Camarri and Pitman](http://ejp.ejpecp.org/article/view/58/115) may be worth a look.

Comment: Does it give information for what happens if $k = \Theta(n^{c})$. Then is $m = O(n^{c+1})$ or $m = O(n^{2c})$ for both $c <1$ and $c >1$?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This answer was for $k$ fixed, rather than $k = \Theta (n)$ as specified in the original question.

You should be able to use (for example) Talagrand's concentration inequality to show that the number of k-sets which are all the same colour is tightly concentrated.  So the critical value for $m$ should satisfy $\binom m k / n^{k-1} \approx 1$, i.e. $m \approx n^{1-1/k}$, which happily agrees with the answer for the birthday problem.

There are lots of details to check here if you want to make sure this argument holds water.

Comment: Could you please explain more? I am unfamiliar with concentration inequalities.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to expand this example right now, but you might find this answer to an older question helpful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119157/runs-in-coin-flips/119165#119165  Concentration inequalities are wonderful tools, and my first port of call when presented with anything remotely resembling random variables on product spaces.

Comment: Interesting. OK. Let me take a look and see what I can gather. Thankyou for the link.

Comment: If $k = \theta(n^{b})$, where $b>0$, would you still need $\theta(n^{2b})$ as $m$ for both $b <1$ and $b>1$?

Comment: If $0 < b << 1$, would the concentration trick show something different?

Comment: Ben do you know what happens if $k = \Theta(n^{c})$. Then is $m = O(n^{c+1})$ or $m = O(n^{2c})$?

Comment: Does it seem possible if $k = n^{1-\delta}$, the critical value approach you mentioned with $m \approx n^{1-\frac{1}{k}}$ will work?